# Android gradle packagingOptions pickFirst and exclude not working

Tags: android, gradle, duplicates, apk, packaging

EclipseLink jar contains some JPA classes. Android build APK fails:

```
Error:Execution failed for  
task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/persistence/Access.class
```

Tried both exclude and pickFirst as following

```
packagingOptions {

    exclude 'javax/persistence/**'
}


packagingOptions {

     pickFirst 'javax/persistence/**'
}

packagingOptions {

     pickFirst 'javax/persistence/Access.class'
}
```

None of them working.

Comment: Have you fixed this?

Answer (score 3):

Having the same requirement I searched for quite some time for a solution.

Unfortunately, at the time of writing, those options only work in app modules! They have no effect whatsoever in library modules.

You have to copy those options to all your final app modules.

Comment: I did copy the pacakingOption in all of my modules but it didn't work

Comment: Were you able to find a fix for this?