# I get error when I try to run the Expo project: Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile, expo

I just switched from web to mobile, and I am pretty new to React Native. My problem is after I created the expo project, I try to run it on Android Studio, but get the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeNativeLibsTask$MergeNativeLibsTaskWorkAction
   > 2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/liblog.so' from inputs:
      - C:\Users\recep\Desktop\software\aa-course\node_modules\react-native-mmkv\android\build\intermediates\library_jni\debug\jni\arm64-v8a\liblog.so
      - C:\Users\recep\Desktop\software\aa-course\node_modules\react-native-quick-crypto\android\build\intermediates\library_jni\debug\jni\arm64-v8a\liblog.so
BUILD FAILED in 24m 36s
483 actionable tasks: 163 executed, 320 from cache
Error: C:\Users\recep\Desktop\software\aa-course\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: C:\Users\recep\Desktop\software\aa-course\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\recep\Desktop\software\aa-course\node_modules\@expo\cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:52:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at cp.emit (C:\Users\recep\Desktop\software\aa-course\node_modules\@expo\cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (C:\Users\recep\Desktop\software\aa-course\node_modules\@expo\cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:17:21) 
    at spawnGradleAsync (C:\Users\recep\Desktop\software\aa-course\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:72:46)
    at Object.assembleAsync (C:\Users\recep\Desktop\software\aa-course\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:52:18)
    at runAndroidAsync (C:\Users\recep\Desktop\software\aa-course\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\run\android\runAndroidAsync.js:35:24)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Only solution I saw thus far is to add `pickFirst` in `packagingOptions` to `build.gradle` but it is already added. What does cause the problem and how it can be solved?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like it doesn't know which native library to pick, e.g. `lib/arm64-v8a/liblog.so`. I suppose they're the same (you can verify this with an md5sum check). What happens if you remove one of them? `pickFirst` doesn't doesn't seem to work for libraries, but works in apps (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731997/android-gradle-packagingoptions-pickfirst-and-exclude-not-working). Do you have multiple `build.gradle` files maybe there's another build script that you should add it to?

Comment: @FelixNovovic I think `liblog.so` is created during running process. For the second question, yes, I have two `build.gradle` files.

Comment: forgot adding. I deleted one `liblog.so` and got the same error. That is why I think it is created during running

Comment: https://forums.expo.dev/t/eas-build-fails-for-android-execution-failed-for-task-mergereleasenativelibs/56633/13

or

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35215

The link above will assist you in finding the answer.